# Seeking a non-permanent cover for unfinished basement ceiling - no drop ceiling, drywall, paint, or frame installation

Tags: basement, ceiling, temporary, unfinished

I am looking to build a home gym in my basement and I do plan to drywall it, but I have specific reasons on why I want to wait for a couple of years. Is there a type of fabric I can staple to the wood?

I do not find it worthwhile to install any wooden pieces to contain this particular solution, again this is in a solution in between me drywalling it. I don't want to use a drop ceiling, or properly finish it, and I do not want to spraypaint it either. Specifically seeking some form of fabric to staple up there, but uncertain as to what kind would work best or be the safest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If no ceiling lights, then maybe house wrap will do.

Comment: Since this is some what outside the realm of "normal" practice, I think it is a matter of your preferences.  May be tarps, bed sheets, painters canvas?  We don't know more about your specific tastes regarding the covering to give a specific answer.  There is no " temporary basement ceiling fabric covering."

Comment: A fabric ceiling covering is a major fire hazard.

Comment: Fireproofed fabric generally isn't very... except compared to un-fireproofed. (And even then, there are stories about one treatment which made things worse...)